# how to get a table width to move in one of my media queries

Tags: css

I am trying to get one of my tables to be wider for my media query of 1024px but it isn't working. I have used width with px or em setting, even % but can't get it to work. I also added the `!important` tag. I am not sure what is overriding it. I am also having problems moving my span tag up or down and have been using either positioning, or `margin-up`, `margin-down`. Any other things I could do to make it move? I also try the `display:flex` but that doesn't help either.

I am not sure which code to put here because all my css code is too long for codepen

```
.admin_create_level1promo textarea {
  width: 25em;
  height:6em;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1em;

}
```

I tried to add margin-bottom and bottom but can't get my textarea to move

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPrgg.png)

php code

```
 echo '<form action="admin_create_level1promo_process.php" method="POST">';

                 echo '<table class="admin_create_level1promo">

                      <tr>
                      <th colspan="3" class="update_title">Welcome to the Create Level 1 Promo Competition\'s Section</th>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Entry ID:</th><td><input type="text" name="entry_id" placeholder="Enter ID"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Name of Competition:</th><td><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Duration of Competition:</th><td><input type="duration" name="duration" placeholder="Enter Duration"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Describe Competition:</th><td><textarea name="describe" placeholder="Enter Description of Competition"></textarea></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Opening Date:</th><td><input type="text" name="opening_date" placeholder="Enter Opening Date"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Closing Date:</th><td><input type="text" name="closing_date" placeholder="Enter Closing Date"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th>Points:</th><td><input type="text" name="points" placeholder="Enter Points"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th></th><td><input type="hidden" name="csrf" value="'.$_SESSION['token'].'"></td>
                      </tr>
                      <tr>
                      <th></th><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Create Level 1 promo Competition"></td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
                      </form>';

    }
}
```

Comment: I think I got it to work but don't know why I have to use min-width

Comment: I can't help you out until you paste your code here!

Comment: The important thing now for me is to get the textarea to move up or down.. I can get it to move left or right

Comment: use position relative

Comment: position relative doesn't work

Comment: Provide your html code

Comment: I actually did it all in php

Comment: I think this is a css problem and it is a trial and error thing using either max width or min width... something is overriding my proble

Comment: I guess most of the options would be to use margin or padding but for this case, I shouldn't use padding...

Comment: sorry guys... I have got it to work with margin-bottom... I thought it didn't work before but maybe I did not set the margin high enough

Comment: I am surprised that margin-bottom doesn't work

Comment: just margin-top

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve. If the textarea has `position`, then you should use `left` or `top` to move it.

Comment: I am also wondering if I should use a min-width for my media query on top of the max width? If I used a max-width media query only, will this create some problems such as moving my other media queries images around etc?

Comment: `<th style="height: 100px">Describe Competition:</th>` add Height as did there. the TH has default height and textarea has about 30px+, I'm assuming, that's why is't not working properly!